# Reference monitoring on GObject

Tags: c, memory, gtk, glib, gobject

What I found is:

https://docs.gtk.org/gobject/method.Object.add_toggle_ref.html

I have this problem:

When signal handler for some GtkWidget is called, I cannot delete this widget. One solution is to create timer and delete it in timer procedure, but what If I call additional messages loop inside event handler routine? I do not known if (in this case) signal for widget are blocked, but maybe I need to destroy parent widget in event handler for child?

One solution is to increase reference count, when entering event handler and decrease it, before quit signal handler for widget. But from what I will known to create timer? I guess, I may save if widget should be destroyed (in property, for example) and check if reference count is (for example): 1. If reference count is equal some value and widget contain information, it should been destroyed, then I create timer with procedure to destroy widget (decreasing reference by 1).
In this case, reference count only be 1 at end of first event handler of widget. When we reach end of signal handler and test that widget should been destroyed, we create timer, so we are 100% sure, that widget will be destroyed outside one's event handler.

Problem is: I got segfault, because I destroy window or widget inside one's event handler. When callback reach bottom and execution flow exit, Gtk+ does something strange with widget.

Only one think is still missing: I cannot read reference count of given GObject.

Comment: https://docs.gtk.org/gobject/method.Object.add_toggle_ref.html I cannot use this, if I cannot increase reference count or stop propagating it. If I can tell: stop propagate destroy notify or prevent object destroy to be done, I can create timer in GToggleNotify and destroy widget in timer proc.

Comment: void
(* GToggleNotify) (
  gpointer data,
  GObject* object,
  gboolean is_last_ref
) is_lastf_ref is FALSE, when there is no other references. Does it mean if I increase reference count inside my callback, it will prevent from other callback to do some task?

Comment: You shouldn't be decreasing the refcount in a signal in any case. For widgets, it's normally the parent widget that is responsible for freeing it (and for toplevel widgets, there's specific APIs). Can you post a bit of code of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I solve the problem. I write how many handlers are ran for widget in special property and add can_destroy function, which test given widget and each child if contains property I set with non-zero value. If can_destroy returns false, I create timer, which invokes can_destroy. If can_destroy inside timer returns false, we exit. In any case, if can_destroy return true, we perform destroy. On timer, additionally, we destroy timer. I will post code, but I must test, what exactly does the trick, because I also change widget_unparent onto box_remove_widget.

Comment: That really doesn't sound like a good solution to be honest ... If it works for you I guess it's fine, but don't be surprised if you're going to run into crashes

Comment: What problem do you try to solve? Your solution seems to be very error-prone.

Comment: ~Alexander Dmitriev: I had problems with segfault, when I destroy widget or parent of it inside it's (or it's parent) signal callback. Only one solution, I've found, is create timer. Problem was: I do not known, which widget handler is running inside handler - I create some abstraction layer, where UI is auto-generated by template system.